# How to query total taken time from story defined til complete in java in Rally?

Tags: java, rally, broadcom, rallyapi

In Rally, I have a requirement where I need to capture the time taken by each story till it get complete.
The approach is basically the story went "In process" till it was "Completed". In simple words I want to capture all the date/time when there is a change in schedule state?

Can anybody give me an example how to query it?

Comment: Can you please some extra details for it ?

Comment: With rally APIs we can query rally tool parameters. So I was just querying how much time that story took overall from the time it dev made it in progress and till it accepted.

Comment: To get time differences between story states, you'll want to use the Lookback API. There are plenty of examples and apps out there that calculate time in state. [Lookback API docs are here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual). You'll have to be logged into Rally to view them. You mentioned using Java, [here's an old, but hopefully still valid Toolkit for working with Lookback API in Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-Lookback-Toolkit). If you try to get something working and get stuck then post the code to be reviewed.